# Optimizing code for foreach

Tags: php

I need to HTML table output like:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>ITEM<td>
    <td>ITEM<td>
    <td>ITEM<td>
</tr>
</table>

<table>
<tr>
    <td>ITEM<td>
    <td>ITEM<td>
    <td>ITEM<td>
</tr>
</table>

<table>
<tr>
    <td>ITEM<td>
    <td>ITEM<td>
    <td>ITEM<td>
</tr>
</table>
```

My code before:

```
<?php $i = 1;?>
<?php foreach ($items as $item): ?>
<?php if ($i == 1 || $i == 4 || $i == 7 ......): ?><table><tr><?php endif; ?>
    <td> CONTENT </td>
<?php if ($i == 3 || $i == 6 || $i == 9 ......):?></table></tr><?php endif;?>
<?php $i++ ?>                                                           
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

My code now:

```
<?php $i = 1;?>
<?php foreach ($items as $item): ?>
<?php if ($i % 3 == 1): ?><table><tr><?php endif; ?>
    <td> CONTENT </td>
<?php if ($i % 3 == 0):?></table></tr><?php endif;?>
<?php $i++ ?>                                                           
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Could you please add a description to your question about what your code does?

Answer (score 4):

I assume the $items array is indexed by numbers, otherwise you have to change the code below to include a counter.

```
foreach ($items as $i => $item) {
    if ($i % 3 == 0) {
        // Do something for 0, 3, 6, 9, ...
    } elseif ($i % 3 == 1) {
        // Do something for 1, 4, 7, 10, ...
    } elseif ($i % 3 == 2) {
        // Do something for 2, 5, 8, 11, ...
    }
}
```

This code uses the [modulo operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) %.

**After your edit**
The following code is a more clear solution to your problem:

```
foreach (array_chunk($items, 3) as $chunk):
    echo '<table><tr>';
    foreach ($chunk as $item):
        echo '<td>' . $item . '</td>';
    endforeach;
    echo '</tr></table>';
endforeach;
```

Comment: Although the modulo operator is very fast, I would save the result of it into a variable (DRY principle).